# "Module x is in x.d which cannot be read" error when compiling a d program

Tags: d

Here is the project structure:

```
.
├── dub.json
├── dub.selections.json
├── dub.userprefs
├── source
│   └── app.d
└── testd2
```

Content of `app.d`

```
import std.stdio;
import scid.matrix;
import colorize: fg, color, cwriteln, cwritefln;


void main()
{
    cwriteln("This is blue.".color(fg.blue));
    auto c = "red";
    cwritefln("This is %s".color(c), c);
}
```

Content of dub.josn:

```
{
    "name": "testd2",
    "description": "A minimal D application.",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2014, kaiyin",
    "authors": ["kaiyin"],
    "dependencies": {
        "colorize": ">=1.0.5"
    }
}
```

Build error:

```
dub build
Building colorize 1.0.5 configuration "library", build type debug.
Running dmd...
Building testd2 ~master configuration "application", build type debug.
Compiling using dmd...
source/app.d(2): Error: module matrix is in file 'scid/matrix.d' which cannot be read
import path[0] = source/
import path[1] = ../../../.dub/packages/colorize-1.0.5/source
import path[2] = /usr/local/Cellar/dmd/2.066.0/include/d2
FAIL .dub/build/application-debug-posix.osx-x86_64-dmd_2066-1DB186F012CD3E69677DBEA746FFBDE1/ testd2 executable
Error executing command build: dmd failed with exit code 1.
```

Any ideas about what went wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my fault, I forgot to specify the dependency in `dub.json`, it should be:

```
{
    "name": "testd2",
    "description": "A minimal D application.",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2014, kaiyin",
    "authors": ["kaiyin"],
    "dependencies": {
        "colorize": ">=1.0.5",
        "scid": ">=0.1.0"
    }
}
```

Next time I see this kind of error, I will remeber to look there.